# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR:

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, php-ini

i am getting this error on current server :

> Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://.......'

and same code and services works on my another server and loacalhost ....

what can be the reason for this error ?

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when the client can't download the remote WSDL.

The PHP configuration setting [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) must be `On` in order for the SOAP Client to access the remote WSDL.

If that doesn't solve it then it means that your current server is stopping PHP from connecting and loading the WSDL. This could be due to a firewall rule or some other outbound connectivity problem.